# Move Value in PHP Array to the Beginning of the Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array similar to this:

```
0 => "red",
1 => "green",
2 => "blue",
3 => "yellow"
```

I want to move yellow to index 0. How do I do this?

Edit: My question is how do I move any one of these elements to the beginning? How would I move green to index 0, or blue to index 0? This question is not exclusively about moving the last element to the beginning.

Comment: Could you say what you want the array to look like afterwards? It could be `yellow, red, green, blue`, `yellow, blue, green, red`, `yellow, green, blue, red` and each of these would have different processes. Furthermore does it always have to be the end to the front or is it an arbitrary position to the front?

Answer (score 30):

This seems like the simplest way to me.  You can move any position to the beginning, not just the last (in this example it moves blue to the beginning).

```
$colours = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

$movecolour = $colours[2];
unset($colours[2]);
array_unshift($colours, $movecolour);
```

Comment: +1 Only correct answer in this thread without strange side effects or missing handling of NULL values. Would've really like to upvote this more or downvote the others more, but it's not possible unfortunately.

Comment: @griffin Agreed!
I was searching about this just to confirm my own implementation, and I was surprised with the complexity of other answers, luckily my implementation was identical with SharpC's one!

Comment: I was looking to see if there was a better way of doing this but it looks like this is probably the best way. For work in production code where I don't know the key, the only difference I made was to do an array_search to find the key of the value I needed and then the unset/unshift on that key.

Answer (score 15):

Probably the most straightforward way

```
array_unshift( $arr, array_pop( $arr ) );
```

### EDIT

Per your comment "how can I take any one subscript from the array and move it to the beginning", my answer above doesn't fully satisfy that request - it *only* works by moving the last element to the 0 index.

This function, however, does satisfy that request

```
/**
 * Move array element by index.  Only works with zero-based,
 * contiguously-indexed arrays
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param integer $from Use NULL when you want to move the last element
 * @param integer $to   New index for moved element. Use NULL to push
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 * 
 * @return array Newly re-ordered array
 */
function moveValueByIndex( array $array, $from=null, $to=null )
{
  if ( null === $from )
  {
    $from = count( $array ) - 1;
  }

  if ( !isset( $array[$from] ) )
  {
    throw new Exception( "Offset $from does not exist" );
  }

  if ( array_keys( $array ) != range( 0, count( $array ) - 1 ) )
  {
    throw new Exception( "Invalid array keys" );
  }

  $value = $array[$from];
  unset( $array[$from] );

  if ( null === $to )
  {
    array_push( $array, $value );
  } else {
    $tail = array_splice( $array, $to );
    array_push( $array, $value );
    $array = array_merge( $array, $tail );
  }

  return $array;
}
```

And, in usage

```
$arr = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow' );

echo implode( ',', $arr ); // red,green,blue,yellow

// Move 'blue' to the beginning
$arr = moveValueByIndex( $arr, 2, 0 );

echo implode( ',', $arr ); // blue,red,green,yellow
```

Comment: @Sarfraz: technically Cups's is more compact (he just initialized the array) and still fits with the question requirements.

Comment: @Reese Moore Cups's code doesn't answer the question as I interpreted it.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Cups's code does exactly what the question asks as the question does not stipulate the end condition other than that `yellow` had to be at the top of the array. Reversing it does just that.

Comment: @ceejayoz: If we can't assume certain things, how are we allowed to assume that the array that we are going to want to shift to the front is always going to be the end of the array?

Comment: My question is how can I take any one subscript from the array and move it to the beginning?

Comment: I like this answer but it seems like there is way to much messing around with the memory. I would think it would just be better to do a simple swap on the two values after the error checking to make sure both of the keys to the array exist, as is done at the top of the provided method here.

Comment: I won't argue with that - I can confess to typing up this answer as a half "answer the question" and half "can I actually manipulate arrays in this way" self-exercise.

Comment: 8/10 would use on production

Comment: -1 First answer doesn't completely answer, and second one is just not correct in all cases, e.g. $a = array( NULL, NULL, NULL ) is still a valid array, but isset($a[0]) === false. Also overly complicated. unset($arr[$k]); array_unshift($arr, $val); - simple, easy, correct. Additional reordering can be done using e.g. array_values.

Answer (score 9):

This function will allow you to move an element to an arbitrary position within the array, while leaving the rest of the array untouched:

```
function array_reorder($array, $oldIndex, $newIndex) {
    array_splice(
        $array,
        $newIndex,
        count($array),
        array_merge(
            array_splice($array, $oldIndex, 1),
            array_slice($array, $newIndex, count($array))
        )
    );
    return $array;
}
```

Hopefully the usage is fairly obvious, so this:

```
$array = array('red','green','blue','yellow',);

var_dump(
    array_reorder($array, 3, 0),
    array_reorder($array, 0, 3),
    array_reorder($array, 1, 3),
    array_reorder($array, 2, 0)
);
```

Will output this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "green"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "blue"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "green"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "red"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "green"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "green"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
}
```

Comment: -1 Only works for integer indexes and is overly complicated (and still doesn't do enough checking of parameters etc.). +1 for achieving additional functionality the OP didn't even ask for ;)

Answer (score 5):

You want to move one of the elements to the beginning. Let's say

```
$old = array(
'key1' =>'value1', 
'key2' =>'value2', 
'key3' =>'value3', 
'key4' =>'value4');
```

And you want to move key3 to the beginnig.

```
$new = array();
$new['key3'] = $old['key3']; // This is the first item of array $new
foreach($old as $key => $value) // This will continue adding $old values but key3
{
if($key != 'key3')$new[$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: +1 For being correct (you should still have used strict comparison on the key), -1 for being inefficient and slow (the code, I mean). Still another +1 because it even works for keeping keys, which array_shift can't (if this would've been asked for, your code would unfortunately probably the most efficient).

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to SharpC's answer but accounts for the fact that you may not know where the value is in the array (it's key) or if it is even set.  The 'if' check will skip over it if the color isn't set or if it's already the first element in the array.

```
$color = 'yellow';
$color_array = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

$key = array_search($color, $color_array);

if ($key > 0) {
   unset($color_array[$key]);
   array_unshift($color_array, $color);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still looking for an answer, here is an alternate way.

```
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$color_to_move = ["yellow"];
$colors_wo_yellow = array_diff($colors, $color_to_move);// This will give an array without "yellow"
//Now add "yellow" as 1st element to $
array_unshift($colors_wo_yellow,$color_to_move[0]);
```

That's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

EDITED

This is an update based on the question and liking the generic aspects of the answer by Peter Bailey. However, the code is too function/memory intensive for me so below just does a simple swap of the $from and $to values. This method does not cause the array in question to be resized at all, it simply swaps to values within it.

Second Edit: I added in some more argument checking as mentioned in the comments.

```
function moveValueByIndex( array $array, $from=null, $to=null )
{
  // There is no array, or there are either none or a single entry
  if ( null === $array || count($array) < 2 )
  {
    // Nothing to do, just return what we had
    return $array;
  }

  if ( null === $from )
  {
    $from = count( $array ) - 1;
  }

  if ( null === $to )
  {
    $to = 0;
  }

  if ( $to == $from )
  {
    return $array;
  }

  if ( !array_key_exists($from, $array) )
  {
    throw new Exception( "Key $from does not exist in supplied array." );
  }

  $value = $array[$from];
  $array[$from] = $array[$to];
  $array[$to] = $value;

  return $array;
}
```

Forgive me if I should have just added this in a comment to Peter's post.. it just was too long to inline all of this there :/

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to remove the default arguments to those parameters! Thanks, also added in a $from == $to and such.

Comment: -1 for not handling NULL elements in array correctly as well as the needless array key check (just makes it so only 0-indexed ordered integer keys work - but for which reason?)

Comment: @griffin How does that not handle a NULL element?

Comment: You throw an exception with the message "Offset $from does not exist" in case of NULL element. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php "... and is not NULL." - using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php would have been more correct

Comment: @griffin Thanks, updated the answer and removed the now not-needed key check to be replaced by array_key_exists()

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
  'red',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
);

$last = array_pop($array);
array_unshift($array, $last);
```

Comment: No longer does what the original post has been updated to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array('red','green', 'blue','yellow');

$b = array_reverse( $a );
```

If your question is how to make the last become the first.

Comment: This'll reverse the entire array, though, not just move 'yellow' to the beginning.

Comment: @ceejayoz: The questioner never specified the state of the array at the end other than that `yellow` was at the beginning.

Comment: I assume if he didn't mention any changes to the rest of the array, he intended for only 'yellow' to change location.

Comment: @ceejayoz: then why shift everything else down, why not simply swap it with `red`, that would involve less change to the array.

Comment: Swapping it with red changes the order of the rest of the array.

Comment: Well thats nice, marked down because the OP asked an ambiguous question - I even took care to explain my point of view! Well of course it reverses the whole array, the hint is in the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$array = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
$last = array_pop($array);
array_unshift($array, $last);
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => yellow [1] => red [2] => green [3] => blue )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't always planning on bringing the very last object to the beginning of the array, this would be the most simplistic way to go about it...

```
$array = array('red','green','blue','yellow');
unset($array[array_search($searchValue, $array)]);
array_unshift($array, $searchValue);
```

Comment: -1 doesn't handle return value of array_search, and if it's only intended for values known to be in the array, it still doesn't handle doubled values, and is needlessly to complex (why search if you know which you want to be moved?)

Answer (score 0):

PHP: move any element to the first or any position:

```
$sourceArray = array(
    0 => "red",
    1 => "green",
    2 => "blue",
    3 => "yellow"
);
// set new order
$orderArray = array(
    3 => '',
    1 => '',
);
$result = array_replace($orderArray, $sourceArray);
print_r($result);
```