# Move array element by associative key to the beginning of an array

Tags: php, arrays

So far all my research has shown that this cannot be achieved without writing lengthy functions such as the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126502/move-value-in-php-array-to-the-beginning-of-the-array)

Surely there is a simpler way of achieving this using the predefined PHP functions?

Just to be clear, I am trying to do the following:

```
$test = array(
    'bla' => 123,
    'bla2' => 1234,
    'bla3' => 12345
);

// Call some cool function here and return the array where the 
// the element with key 'bla2' has been shifted to the beginning like so
print_r($test);
// Prints bla2=1234, bla=>123 etc...
```

I have looked at using the following functions but have so far have not been able to write a solution myself.

1. [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)
2. [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

### To Summarize

I would like to:

1. Move an element to the **beginning** of an array
2. ... whilst maintaining the associative array keys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems, *funny*, to me. But here ya go:

```
$test = array(
    'bla' => 123,
    'bla2' => 1234,
    'bla3' => 12345
);

//store value of key we want to move
$tmp = $test['bla2'];

//now remove this from the original array
unset($test['bla2']);

//then create a new array with the requested index at the beginning
$new = array_merge(array('bla2' => $tmp), $test);

print_r($new);
```

Output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [bla2] => 1234
    [bla] => 123
    [bla3] => 12345
)
```

You could turn this into a simple function that takes-in a key and an array, then outputs the newly sorted array.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why I didn't default to using `uksort`, but you can do this a bit cleaner:

```
$test = array(
    'bla' => 123,
    'bla2' => 1234,
    'bla3' => 12345
);

//create a function to handle sorting by keys
function sortStuff($a, $b) {
    if ($a === 'bla2') {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

//sort by keys using user-defined function
uksort($test, 'sortStuff');

print_r($test);
```

This returns the same output as the code above.

Comment: I did pretty much exactly this and it didnt work... I must have made a mistake. Will try again, thanks +1

Comment: @BenCarey Glad to help, check-out the update too, maybe a little cleaner way to do the same thing.

Comment: Well this may be the most embarrassing programming error for me to ever admit, but the code I originally had (exactly the same as yours), was indeed correct. However, I was printing the wrong array so wasn't seeing the result... Smooooooooth. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly the answer to Ben's question (is that bad?) - but this is optimised for bringing a list of items to the top of the list.

```
  /** 
   * Moves any values that exist in the crumb array to the top of values 
   * @param $values array of options with id as key 
   * @param $crumbs array of crumbs with id as key 
   * @return array  
   * @fixme - need to move to crumb Class 
   */ 
  public static function crumbsToTop($values, $crumbs) { 
    $top = array(); 
    foreach ($crumbs AS $key => $crumb) { 
      if (isset($values[$key])) { 
        $top[$key] = $values[$key]; 
        unset($values[$key]); 
      } 
    } 
    return $top + $values;
  }
```