# Rearrange the object based on given order

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the below data value for  `print_r($summary->Aging);`
I want to rearrange the order of the array object based on `AgingType Not Due,< 30,31 to 60 ,61-90 ,91-180 ,181-360,361-720,> 720` in php

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => < 30 [AgingValue] => 114287 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 31 to 60 [AgingValue] => 76806 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 61-90 [AgingValue] => 0 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 91-180 [AgingValue] => 0 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 181-360 [AgingValue] => 2400 )
[5] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 361-720 [AgingValue] => 0 )
[6] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => > 720 [AgingValue] => 0 )
[7] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => Not Due [AgingValue] => 0 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => < 30 [AgingValue] => 27159 )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 31 to 60 [AgingValue] => 0 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 61-90 [AgingValue] => 0 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 91-180 [AgingValue] => 0 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 181-360 [AgingValue] => 0 )
[5] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => 361-720 [AgingValue] => 0 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => > 720 [AgingValue] => 0 )
[7] => stdClass Object ( [AgingType] => Not Due [AgingValue] => 0 ) )
```

I have tried `usort($summary->Aging)` but not able to sort.
I have 3 more set of array like this in `print_r($summary->Aging);`
I want `not Due` at the begeing

Comment: Did you intend to give two example arrays?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, include [example] of your code, improve code formatting,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Comment: Seems like you arrays are already almost sorted. All you really need to do is take "Not Due" from the end and place it at the beginning.

Comment: ya I need not Due in first

Comment: Then you might take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126502/move-value-in-php-array-to-the-beginning-of-the-array).